# How can I install UWP appx file from my file server?

Tags: uwp, mdm, sideloading, appx

I have a question about UWP appx installization. We want to install without using windows app store. so, I will upload appx file to my file server. and then, How can i install that appx file from server to local devices. Is it possible without using powershell command?
Please tell me more information about this.

[How to access UWP application settings set by MDM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40342703/how-to-access-uwp-application-settings-set-by-mdm)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/commercialize/customize/mdm/enterprisemodernappmanagement-csp

Comment: Just use the CSP as described in the link you've posted?

Comment: Yes, I know but I don't know how i can use CSP.

Comment: Okay. CSP is used by you creating a MDM server and then issuing some MDM commands. You need to implement a WSTEP protocol and register all devices. Note that all users will have to have local admin on their machines in order to enroll. Once you got the device talking to the server it will use SyncML. You can then create a XML command to install the .appx using the data from CSP reference.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [SCCM to deploy AppX](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/18c30424-aacf-4523-80d5-c5f10d04dd8d/using-sccm-2012-to-deploy-appx-packages?forum=configmanagerapps) packages?